# Display the first element of a has_many relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**app/models/product.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Product = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  pictures: DS.hasMany('picture', { async: true })
});

export default Product;
```

**app/models/pictures.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Picture = DS.Model.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  alt: DS.attr('string')
});

export default Picture;
```

In the `product` index view I can display all `pictures` with this code:

```
{{#each picture in product.pictures}}
  <img {{bind-attr src=picture.url}} alt="example">
{{/each}}
```

How can I display just the first `picture`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
<img src={{product.pictures.firstObject.url}} alt="example">
```

The properties `firstObject` and `lastObject` are available in Ember.

Also note, you don't need to use bind-attr anymore.